# Is my proof right? (show that there are no isolated point in the real numbers)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Question:** Prove that in the metric space of all real numbers there are no isolated points.

**Proof:** Showing that for every ball with radius $\epsilon>0$ and center $x_0$, exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-x_0|< \epsilon$ is equivalent to show that there are no isolated point in the real numbers. Then, take $x =\frac{\epsilon}{2}+x_0$ which implies $|x-x_0|=|\frac{\epsilon}{2}+x_0-x_0|=\frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$. $\Box$

I would appreciate some suggestions on how to improve or correct.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you should prove is that there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $\color{red}{0<}|x-x_0|<\varepsilon$; without that $0<|x-x_0|$, you could simply take $x=x_0$, which proves nothing. However, since your $x$ is actually distinct from $x_0$, there is no problem.